# Why my nginx as a service is not working in windows server 2016

Tags: nginx, windows-services, windows-server-2016

I've created nginx as service using nssm. Service is created successfully, but its not starting properly.
[image: This is the error i get when i try to start service]

This is what i see in system event log for nginx error

[image: nginx service error image]

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: Have you checked system log as the error suggests? What's in it?

Comment: @anemyte, edited my question with error screenshot.